# Configuration->General Settings keep getting cleared. In core_config_data table path 'genera' value 0 keeps appearing

Tags: configuration, core-config-data, system-config

This just started happening recently in our development environment. The row

> id default 0 general 0

keeps getting inserted into core_config_data. Every time I delete it manually via sql, it comes back as if its from some cron job.

So the point is that when this row is in the database, my entire General tab under system->configuration is cleared/reset/blank/deselected. (this messes up the frontend also where all the countries disappear from drop down.)

This is driving me crazy, how can I pinpoint what is causing this entry to keep reappearing? Could it be from a rogue cron job, config.xml, or setup installer sql?

*Update: I believe the SQL query causing this is:

> INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`value`) VALUES ('0')

Found that query while searching logs for all queries being run.

Magento version 1.9.1.0

Comment: In our case it was an extension.
Celigo Connector v3.4.2 We are still working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Extension installations write to the DB too. 
 
Have you recently installed some?
Deactivate those as a start of diagnosis.